# "Dark Souls Series" tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Should there be a [dark-souls-series](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dark-souls-series) and/or [dark-souls-lore](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dark-souls-lore) tag?

There are a few questions I have found that could use one or both of these tags, and with multiple games in the series now, (for some reason) people can confuse the [dark-souls](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dark-souls) tag as a tag for the series, rather than the first installment.

Normally I would go straight ahead with this, but the issue is that if the community is (albeit rarely) already confusing the tags, adding more would just exacerbate the issue.

Some examples of this might be:

- [Lore reason behind dissolving of the corpses in Dark Souls](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/267190/73976) - Uses the [dark-souls](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dark-souls) and [dark-souls-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dark-souls-3) tags
- [Does Dark Souls 2 allow random online mode?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/239569/does-dark-souls-2-allow-random-online-mode) - uses the [dark-souls-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dark-souls-2) and [dark-souls](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dark-souls) tags, yet is asking specifically about DkS2.
- [In terms of lore, how do Miracles work?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/264212/in-terms-of-lore-how-do-miracles-work) - this question is asking about the series, and has used the [dark-souls-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dark-souls-3), [dark-souls-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dark-souls-2) and [dark-souls](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dark-souls) tags correctly, but this is a question that might benefit from a generic tag, as it is not specifically asking bout a comparison between the games, but the series as a whole.

Comment: [Dark-souls-series] would match our current naming convention

Comment: Can a tag be renamed? I.e. could the [dark-souls] tag be changed to [dark-souls-1]?

Comment: Not easily by regular users (requiring literally editing every question to remove/add the tag), but I believe mods can do it in one fell swoop. Having said that, I believe the precedent is to not append '1's to the title. See the edit history and convo between shanodin and I [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/202184/what-is-the-quickest-way-to-farm-1-million-bolts) regarding Ratchet 1. [tag:sonic-the-hedgehog] is another tag where this isn't the case.

Comment: So in the case of the Sonic tag, the explanation of using the "series" tag for general use was added. So I guess it's just down to whether or not it's necessary.

Comment: yep. Pretty sure I wrote that excerpt as well (in the interest of full disclosure) :-)

Comment: Can you provide a few examples of questions which you think would benefit from the tag?

Answer (score 2):

The [dark-souls-series](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dark-souls-series) tag now exists, with 4 questions using it. If you come across any other questions that should use the series tag, please edit them.*

I have added a tag excerpt stub describing how the tag should be used. Feel free to improve upon it if needed.

<sub>* Try not to flood the front page with tag edits. Edit when you see a problem, don't go looking for one.</sub>